# Cells/Rows in the <SectionList/> loading slowly on Android

Tags: react-native

I use the new API `<SectionList/>` to build a list UI, but I found issues running on Android devices.

1. While scrolling down with `SectionList`, only a few new cells/rows can be displayed at once. You need to scroll `SectionList` down again to display the next a few new cells/rows, and wait for the next cells are ready to be displayed. It works not the same on the iOS.
2. When reaching the last item in the `SectionList`, I tried to scroll up quickly to the first item in the `SectionList`, and it display a blank view with a few seconds till the cells are rendered.

I have hundred rows (country list) for display, and the user experience is bad. The user takes many seconds to reach the last item in the country list, and takes many seconds to show the previous rows after scrolling up quickly.

```
export default class LoginCountryList extends React.Component {

  props: LoginCountryListProps;
  static defaultProps = {
    data: {},
  };

  renderRow = (rowItem: any) => {
    console.log('render row:');
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight
        onPress={() => this.props.onSelectRow(rowItem.item)}
      >
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.rowLeftText}>{rowItem.item.name}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.rowRightText}>{`+${rowItem.item.ccc}`}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    )
  };

  renderSectionHeader = (sectionItem: any) => (
    <View
      style={styles.sectionHeader}
    >
      <Text style={styles.sectionHeaderText}>{sectionItem.section.title}</Text>
    </View>
  );

  render() {

    console.log('re-render section list')
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <NavigationBar.TextStyle
          title={title}
          leftText={leftText}
          onLeft={this.props.onBack}
        />
        <SectionList
          style={styles.listView}
          sections={this.props.data}
          renderItem={this.renderRow}
          renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

// data:

const data = [
  // first section
  {
    "title": "A",
    "key": "A",
    "data": [
      // first row
      {
        "ccc": "93",
        "countryCode": "AF",
        "currencyCode": "AFN",
        "currencySymbol": "؋",
        "name": "Afghanistan",
        "key": "AF"
      },
      {
        "ccc": "355",
        "countryCode": "AL",
        "currencyCode": "ALL",
        "currencySymbol": "Lek",
        "name": "Albania",
        "key": "AL"
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

I tried to log in the `renderItem` callback when `SectionList` did display, and it calls `renderItem` hundred times for displaying only 15 rows in the first section.

Log a constant string `render row:` with hundred times when the SectionList did display:

[image]

Log the indexes of the items when the SectionList did display. The same row did render multiple times when the SectionList did display.

[image]

Did use `SectionList` wrongly? How do I do to fix it?

#### Environment

1. `react-native -v`: `0.45.1` & `0.46.1` (tried both version)
2. `node -v`: `v7.8.0`
3. `npm -v`: `4.2.0`
4. `yarn --version` (if you use Yarn): `0.22.0`
5. Target Platform (e.g. iOS, Android): Android
6. Development Operating System (e.g. macOS Sierra, Windows 10): macOS
7. Build tools (Xcode or Android Studio version, iOS or Android SDK version, if relevant): Android SDK 25.0.2